# What's the best way to refactor insert_after and insert_before methods for a linked-list node?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, linked-list

I already tried using the `send` method, but it ended up being almost unreadable and as long as the previous code. Is there a simple way in Ruby to refactor code like this?

```
def insert_before(data)
  node = Node.new(data)
  node.next = self
  node.prev = @prev

  @prev.next = node unless @prev.nil?

  @prev = node
end

def insert_after(data)
  node = Node.new(data)
  node.prev = self
  node.next = @next

  @next.prev = node unless @next.nil?

  @next = node
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem very long to me, and it's very easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have is fine, but you may want to put the common bits of the two methods in a separate method.

```
def insert_before(data)
  node = insert_node(data, self, @prev)
  @prev.next = node unless @prev.nil?
  @prev = node
end

def insert_after(data)
  node = insert_node(data, @next, self)
  @next.prev = node unless @next.nil?
  @next = node
end

def insert_node(data, from, to)
  node = Node.new(data)
  node.next = to
  node.prev = from
  node
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought about that. I now simply extended my constructor to take a `prev` and `next` argument, so instead of creating a new `insert_node` method, I can simple use `Node.new`.